# How do I update a UITableViewCell after an event

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to click on a cell and first of all I want to link an account (Dropbox or Calendars or Reminders or others) and at the same time if the link is successful i want to checkmark the cell.
My problem is that once linked the account I have to tap again on the cell to add the checkmark.Can do these two operations with a single tap on the cell?

---

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (![[DBSession sharedSession]isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
              if ([[DBSession sharedSession]isLinked]) 
                  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

}

Comment: ? why can't you run the checkmark code with it. This makes no sense. Post your code!

Comment: I can not directly put the checkmark because for example if I want to link to dropbox once you open the login page if the user clicks on the x does not access he put the same checkmark and instead should not put

Comment: if that is your issue, your question makes no sense. Your asking how to run 2 pieces of code at the same time and have just said it is impossible to do so. I'm guessing your trying to ask something more like "Hpw do I update a UITableViewCell after an event", the event being that the user links an account. again post your code so we can see

Comment: I'm sorry I do not speak English very well and did not know how to write it

Comment: Ok so you have posted the code to set the checkmark ... that important part was to see how you are connecting the accounts. The idea being that, somewhere you should get a callback to say it happened and inside there you run the above code to update the cell

Comment: can you show me how to do it with the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing what kind of callbacks you have to see if the user has connected their account. The only thing I can advise you to do is to run the below code on `viewDidAppear`.

Note I have no idea if this will work because I'm not sure if `viewDidAppear` will even be triggered after the user see's the screen to add the account. Because I don't know how thats being implemented either.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Check Dropbox
    NSIndexPath dropboxIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:dropboxIndex];
    if (![[DBSession sharedSession]isLinked]) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
              if ([[DBSession sharedSession]isLinked]) 
                  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    // Check calendar
    // same as above


    // Check reminder
    // same as above
}
```

**EDIT**

You first of all need to look at this. [Dropbox SDK - linkFromController: delegate or callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213653/dropbox-sdk-linkfromcontroller-delegate-or-callback)

The above is how you detect that dropbox has been linked.

Then when the `appDelegate` gets the successful message, use `NSNotificationCenter` to send a message to the screen and run the code I gave you above.

Comment: @Luca i've edited my answer, after I did your research for you. Please next time put in some effort to solving your own issue, or bare minimum supply all the necessary code you have so that people can actually understand the issue

Comment: ok thanks for the help you're giving me so much and I'm sorry

Comment: @Luca don't forget to mark top answer / upvote my answer if it fixes your issue

Answer (score 1):

When You select cell first time the cell is checkmarked and when you select other cell then all other are deselect.

put This code in Didselect method.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cellStr = cell.textLabel.text;
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Put this code in Diddeselect Method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```